# Procedure expects parameter which was not Supplied error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure in DB that accepted 4 parameters.when i call this procedure from  SQLDatasource and pass its parameters through sqldatasource wizard i get the following error

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Procedure or function 'director_proc' expects parameter '@Department', which was not supplied.

below is code for sqldatasource tags and stored procedure

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
SelectCommand="director_proc" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
 <SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ASPxComboBox1" DbType="String" 
DefaultValue="Enterprise solution" Name="Department" PropertyName="Value" 
Type="String" />
 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ASPxComboBox2" DbType="String" 
DefaultValue="Enterprise operations" Name="Section" PropertyName="Value" 
Type="String" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="MonthEdit1" DbType="Int16" DefaultValue="7" 
Name="Month" PropertyName="Month" Type="Decimal" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ASPxComboBox3" DbType="Int16" 
 DefaultValue="2013" Name="Year" PropertyName="Value" Type="Decimal" />
 </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

stored procedure

```
    USE [AccessmgmtDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[director_proc]    Script Date: 10/08/2013 14:22:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[director_proc]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Department nchar(50),
@Section nchar(50),
@Month numeric,
@Year numeric
AS
BEGIN
    if(@Section is null)
    SELECT SSNO ,Full_Name,152.5 [Working Hours],sum(diff) Actual_Hours,MONTH(date) as month,Year(date) Year
         ,(case when 152.5-sum([diff])<0 then 0 else 152.5-sum([diff])end) as [Missing Hours]
         ,(case when 152.5-sum([diff])<0 then 0 else (152.5-sum([diff]))/8.5 end) as [wanted days]
         ,section
         FROM attendance2
         where Department=@Department and MONTH ( date )=@Month and Year(date)=@Year
         group by SSNO,Full_Name,section,MONTH(date),Year(date) order by full_name;
         else
         SELECT SSNO ,Full_Name,152.5 [Working Hours],sum(diff) Actual_Hours,MONTH(date) as month,Year(date) Year
         ,(case when 152.5-sum([diff])<0 then 0 else 152.5-sum([diff])end) as [Missing Hours]
         ,(case when 152.5-sum([diff])<0 then 0 else (152.5-sum([diff]))/8.5 end) as [wanted days]
         ,section
         FROM attendance2
         where Department=@Department and MONTH ( date )=@Month and Year(date)=@Year and section=@Section
         group by SSNO,Full_Name,section,MONTH(date),Year(date) order by full_name;
END
```

Comment: Do you have this working on another page? When is the SQLDatasource trying to retrieve data?

Comment: Q1:no,this first page to use this procedure
Q2:yes

Comment: Well, I mean to say, do you use a SQLDatasource on another page, including any other stored procedures you might call. And 'yes' is not a when. After what event does the SQLDatasource call the stored procedure?

Comment: ok
no i don't have other procedures except this one in the whole application.
this event is called when button called browse is triggered.
but initially i just want to get the data from sqldatasource wizard where i passed all prameters manually.
thanks for consideration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys good news is i successfully solved the problem.
i was using odbc connection and seems that error occur when passing the parameters through ODBC connection.so i remove the odbc and replace it with regular sql connection and everything goes fine.

thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ASPxComboBox1" DbType="String" DefaultValue="Enterprise solution" Name="Department" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
```

Try:

```
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ASPxComboBox1" DbType="String" DefaultValue="Enterprise solution" Name="Department" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter.propertyname.aspx

Comment: i'm still believe that by applying your suggestion it will not work also because basically now i trying to get the data manually from sqldatasource wizard with default parameters and i get this error.

Comment: PropertyName should be SelectedValue not Value

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are binding to a DevExpress Combo Box. Try setting `AutoPostback="true"` on your ASPxComboBox controls. Also, make sure your SqlDataSource is in the same naming container as the DevExpress controls... they've had issues with that in the past, but I haven't used them in years so I don't know if it is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SelectedItem.Value` instead of values for Control parameters for combobox .

```
 <SelectParameters>
      <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ASPxComboBox1" DbType="String" 
       DefaultValue="Enterprise solution" Name="Department"  
       PropertyName="SelectedItem.Value" 
       Type="String" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ASPxComboBox2" DbType="String" 
       DefaultValue="Enterprise operations" Name="Section"     
       PropertyName="SelectedItem.Value" 
       Type="String" />
   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="MonthEdit1" DbType="Int16" DefaultValue="7" 
       Name="Month" PropertyName="Month" Type="Decimal" />
   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ASPxComboBox3" DbType="Int16" 
       DefaultValue="2013" Name="Year" PropertyName="SelectedItem.Value" Type="Decimal" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

Comment: i'm still believe that by applying your suggestion it will not work also because basically now i trying to get the data manually from sqldatasource wizard with default parameters and i get this error.